# Can not able to pass list of model into View @model Tuple<List<ParentModel>,List<ChildModel>,List<SubChildModel>, List<ActionModel>, string []>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I want my model to be a

```
@model Tuple<List<ParentModel>, List<ChildModel>, List<SubChildModel>, List<ActionModel>, string []>
```

when I paste it into the `@model` declaration it seems to only pick out the `ParentModel` part of the tuple. So I have access only `ParentModel`, i.e Only item1.

If i pass 4 elements , for example

```
@model Tuple<List<ParentModel>, List<ChildModel>, List<ActionModel>, string[]>
```

then its working fine. But I want to pass more then 4 elements in`@model`.